# Installing Ruby

Tags: installation, ruby

I found a tutorial in this [site](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-install-ruby-on-rails-on-ubuntu-12-04-lts-precise-pangolin-with-rvm) showing how to install Ruby. The problem is I found the terminal is asking to install packages that are already installed

```
Reading package lists... 
Installing required packages: gawk, g++,
libreadline6-dev, zlib1g-dev, libssl-dev, libyaml-dev, libsqlite3-dev,
sqlite3, autoconf, libgdbm-dev, libncurses5-dev, automake, libtool,
bison, libffi-dev
```